# Have I made a mistake on the master and a branch?

Tags: git, github

I'm a novice on git/github and I suspect I might have made a mistake with a branch without realising it until now. A few months ago I managed to get everything up and running with git and everything still seems to work fine.

Now, for the first time I want to create a branche and when reading the docs, I noticed that my config might already have a branche that I never intended to create. I think that I only need a master branche right now and then for the new feature I want to test I will create a branche.

Could someone tell me if I'm currently working correctly with just a Master or do I also have a branche without knowing it?

When I run: **git status**

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

When I run: **git branch -r**

```
  origin/master
  origin/—set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

When I run: **git remote -v**

```
origin  git@github.com:TheGabeMan/NestReporter.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:TheGabeMan/NestReporter.git (push)
```

When I run: **git branch**

```
* master
  —set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

So I'm wondering if "--set-upstream-to master origin/master" is an incorrect parameter I used which accidentaly converted to a name or is it the correct naming for the remote master?

Comment: can you run `git branch --all`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it looks like you have inadvertently create both a local and remote branch named "—set-upstream-to=origin/master".

To delete that branch locally, you should be able to run `git branch -d "—set-upstream-to=origin/master"`

To delete the remote branch, as long as you are using a relatively recent version of git, the most straightforward thing to do is `git push origin --delete "—set-upstream-to=origin/master"`.

Comment: In the mean time I tried several other things and was able to remove the "--set-upstream-to=origin/master" but a different branch I was testing with has now become out of sync.... Sorry :-)

Running: git branch --all  gives:
`* master

  remotes/origin/dhtmlxCalendar

  remotes/origin/master`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Tried a few more deletes and eventually solved it by running git fetch -p.

When I now run `git branch -a`, the result is:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Looks good to me now :-)